# Spectral description of the Kronecker factor

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$
$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$

## Definitions

Let $(X, \mc X, \mu)$ be probability space and $T:X\to X$ be an invertible measure preserving transformation.
Let us write $L^2$ to mean $L^2(X, \mc X, \mu)$.
Let $U_T$ be the associated Koopman operator on $L^2$.
We may write $Tf$ in place of $U_Tf$.

We say that $\lambda\in \C$ is an **eigenvalue** of the measure preserving system $(X, T)$ if there is a nonzero function $f\in L^2$ such that $Tf=\lambda f$.
Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$, we say that $f\in L^2$ is an **eigenfunction** corresponding to $\lambda$ if $Tf=\lambda f$.
Let $\mc X_1$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of all the eigenfunctions.
Let $H_{pp}$ be the closure of the span of all the eigenfunctions.

We say that $f\in L^2$ is **almost periodic** if the closure of $\set{T^nf:\ n\in \Z}$ is compact in $L^2$.
It is shows in Proposition 2 of [this blog post of Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/254a-lecture-11-compact-systems/), assuming ergodicity of $T$, that$f$ is almost periodic if and only if $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mc X_1$.
In other words, $f$ is almost periodic if and only if $f\in L^2(X, \mc X_1, \mu)$.

## Question

Exercise 5 in [this blog post of Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/254a-lecture-11-compact-systems/) asks to show the following.

> **Exercise.** Assume $T$ is $\mu$-ergodic and $f\in L^2$ be given. Then $f\in L^2(X, \mc X_1, \mu)$ if and only if $f$ is in $H_{pp}$.

(I do not think ergodicty is required but right now I am content with the ergodic case.)

The hint given is that first one may use the fact that $f\in L^2(X, \mc X_1, \mu)$ if and only if $f$ if almost periodic and also use the fact that the product of two eigenfunctions is also an eigenfunction.
I am unable to see how this hint helps solve the question at hand.
Independent of the hint, I thought of using the spectral theorem to push the information to $\mathbb T=\R/\Z$.
The almost periodicity of $f$ in $L^2$ gives that the constant function $1$ is almost periodic in $L^2(\mathbb T, \nu)$, where $\nu$ is the spectral measure corresponding to $f$.
However, I couldn't make any progress using this.

Comment: Your approach using the spectral theorem will succeed.  A further hint is to split $\nu$ into components $\nu_0+\nu_1$, where $\nu_0$ is a sum of atomic measures (i.e. $\nu_0 = \sum_{n} c_n\delta_{x_n}$)  and $\nu_1$ is continuous, meaning $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$ for all $x.$

Comment: @JohnGriesmer I thought about your comment. The nonzero eigenfunctions are precisely the functions which are supported at a single point of positive measure. So if the continuous part of $\nu$ is $0$ then $1$ can be written as a sum of eigenfunctions. So I guess almost periodicity of $1$ is equivalent to the fact that the continuous part of $\nu$ vanishes (though I do not see how to prove it yet). Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @JohnGriesmer I am stuck. Assuming $1$ is almost periodic, I get that the set $\{\chi_n:\ n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is precompact in $L^2(\mathbb T, \nu)$, where $\chi_n$ is the $n$-th character. I am not able to see how I can use this. Can you please help.

Comment: You want to prove that if $\{\chi_n:n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is precompact, then $\nu$ is purely atomic.  [Wiener's lemma (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_lemma) will help you prove the contrapositive: if $\nu$ is not purely atomic, then the set of characters is not precompact.  It's probably easiest to work this out by first proving the following special case: if $\nu$ is continuous, then the set of characters is not precompact.  Also Wiener's lemma has a very nice proof which is worthwhile on its own, if you've never seen it before.

Comment: @JohnGriesmer So let $\nu$ be a continuous probability measure on $\mathbb T$ and I want to show that the characters cannot form a precompact set. Using Wiener's lemma, the coninuity of $\nu$ yeilds that $\hat \nu(n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ away from a density $0$ set. But I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: I misread the question; see my answer for an outline to solve Exercise 5.  The suggestions I made in the comments will help you prove Proposition 2 of Tao's blog post using Hilbert space facts and spectral theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an outline of the proof of Exercise 5.

To prove $L^2(X,\mathcal X_1,\mu) \subset H_{pp}$, assume $f\in L^2(X,\mathcal X_1,\mu)$.  Since $\mathcal X_1$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of sets with respect to which all the eigenfunctions are measurable, we know that $f$ can be approximated in $L^2(\mu)$ by a linear combination of products of eigenfunctions.  Since products of eigenfunctions are again eigenfunctions, this means that $f$ can be approximated by a linear combination of eigenfunctions.  Thus $f\in H_{pp}$.

To prove the reverse inclusion, assume $f\in H_{pp}$.  Then $f$ can be approximated by linear combinations of eigenfunctions.  Since all eigenfunctions are measurable with respect to $\mathcal X_1$, this means that $f$ can be approximated by elements of $L^2(X,\mathcal X_1,\mu)$.  Since the latter space is closed, we have that $f\in L^2(X,\mathcal X_1,\mu)$.

Comment: From the line "Since $\mathcal X_1$ is the smallest [$\sigma$] algebra ..." it seems what you are using is the following: Let $\mathcal F\subseteq L^2$ be a collection of functions and let $\mathcal Y$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal F$. Then if $f\in L^2$ is $\mathcal Y$-measurbale, we can approximate $f$ in $L^2$ arbitrarily well by linear combinations of products of functions in $\mathcal F$. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I couldn't prove the quoted statement. Here is a separate thread where I have asked it as a problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683722/ I hope you can take a look.

Comment: Rerain has provided a counterexample to the quoted statment in the above mentioned thread. I am fuessing that if one assumes that $\mathcal F$ is an algebra then the statment can still hold.

Comment: Yes; my apologies.  I misread your comment as indicating that $\mathcal F$ is already an algebra.

Comment: The set of eigenfunctions form an algebra when $T$ is ergodic. Do you know if the exercise is still true if we drop ergodicity? I have asked a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685496/