# Relation between $\sigma$-algebras generated by $L^2$-eigenfunctions and $L^\infty$-eigenfunctions.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$ $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}$

Let $(X, \mc X, \mu)$ be a probability space and $T:X\to X$ be an invertible measure preserving transformation.
Let $U_T$ be the associated Koopman operator, and we will write $Tf$ in place of $U_Tf$.
We define eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this measure preserving systems in two cases.

***The $L^\infty$ case.*** We say $\lambda\in \C$ is an **eigenvalue** if there is a nonzero $f\in L^\infty$ such that $Tf=\lambda f$.
Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$, we say $f\in L^\infty$ is an **eigenfunction** if $Tf=\lambda f$.
Let $\mc F_\infty$  be the collection of all the eigenfunctions in $L^\infty$.

***The $L^2$ case.*** We say $\lambda\in \C$ is an **eigenvalue** if there is a nonzero $f\in L^2$ such that $Tf=\lambda f$.
Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$, we say $f\in L^2$ is an **eigenfunction** if $Tf=\lambda f$.
Let $\mc F_2$  be the collection of all the eigenfunctions in $L^2$.

It is clear that $\mc F_\infty\subseteq \mc F_2$.
Let $\mc X_\infty$ and $\mc X_2$ be the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $\mc F_\infty$ and $\mc F_2$ respectively.
So we have $\mc X_\infty\subseteq \mc X_2$.

> **Question.** Is the containment $\mc X_\infty\subseteq \mc X_2$ actually an equality in general?

If we assume that $T$ is ergodic then any eigenfunction $f\in L^2$ has the property that $|f|$ is constant $\mu$-a.e.
So there is no difference between $L^2$-eigenfunctions and $L^\infty$-eigenfunctions in the case that $T$ is ergodic.

For the general case I thought of appealing to ergodic decomposition (by assuming that $(X, \mc X)$ is regular).
Let $\mc E$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of all the $T$-invariant sets (up to a set of measure $0$), and $x\mapsto \mu_x^{\mc E}:X\to \mathscr P(X)$ be the ergodic decomposition of $\mu$, where $\mathscr P(X)$ denotes the set of all the probability measures on $X$.
Assume that $\mc E$ is countably generated.
Each ($\mu$-almost each actually) $\mu_x^{\mc E}$ is an ergodic $T$-invariant measure with the property that $\mu_{Tx}^{\mc E} = \mu_x^{\mc E}$.
Further, if we define $[x]_{\mc E}=\bigcap_{x\in E\in \mc E} E$, then $\mu_x^{\mc E}([x]_{\mc E})=1$.

Now let $f\in L^2$ be an arbitrary eigenfunction corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Then the map $f1_{[x]_{\mc E}}$ is an eigenfunction in $L^2(X, \mc X, \mu_x^{\mc E})$ and therefore, by the fact that $\mu_x^{\mc E}$ is $T$-ergodic, it is an eigenfunction in $L^\infty(X, \mc X, \mu_x^{\mc E})$.
In fact, $f1_{[x]_{\mc E}}$ is in $L^\infty(X, \mc X, \mu)$.
So if there were only finitely many ergodic components then we could write $f$ as a sum of finitely many $L^\infty$-eigenfunctions.
However, this is not clear when we have infinitely many ergodic components.

Comment: dude, u gave two containments and then asked about "this containment"

Comment: @mathworker21 I have editied mu post.

Comment: it seems tao answered your question, but i dont get his answer. how is $\frac{\arctan|f|}{|f|}f$ an eigenfunction?

Comment: @mathworker21 We have $Tf=\lambda f$ where $|\lambda| =1$. If we compose $((\arctan |f|)/|f|)f$ with $T$, we get $\lambda ((\arctan |\lambda f|)/|\lambda f|)f = \lambda ((\arctan |f|)/| f|)f$

Comment: i don't understand the last equality. why does the $\lambda$ come out of the arctan?

Comment: $\lambda$ hasn't come out of $\arctan$. That $\lambda$ comes because $Tf=\lambda f$.

Comment: can u rewrite your comment to be a complete, fully explained sentence. i dont see why $\lambda ((\arctan |\lambda f|)/|\lambda f|)f = \lambda ((\arctan |f|)/| f|)f$ holds or what exactly u are syaing by it

Comment: First we note that $T|f| = |Tf| = |\lambda f| = |\lambda| |f|$. Since the Koopmap operator is unitary, we have $|\lambda| = 1$. Therefore $T|f| = |f|$.

Therefore

$$
(\frac{\arctan |f|}{|f|}f)\circ T = \frac{\arctan |Tf|}{|Tf|}Tf = \frac{\arctan |f|}{|f|}\lambda f
$$

Comment: ohhh, so the answer to my first comment was "it doesn't come out of the arctan, but it does go away because $|\lambda| = 1$". in your most recent comment, in your last equality, you're using $|\lambda| = 1$ also. i thought u were taking the $\lambda$ out of the arctan and then cancelling it with the $\lambda$ in the denominator. sorry about that! thanks for explaining

Comment: In my last equality I am using $|Tf| = T|f| = |f|$. Of course, this is simply because $|\lambda| = 1$.